# Align Group Of DIVs Center Inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I am looking to something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EDskx/) but for multiple DIV's? I have uploaded a page showing what I currently have which can be found [here](http://www.splicepro.com.au/center_divs).

Also on Dreamweaver it displays each item as having a 20px padding around them, however on Google Chrome it does not display the same. I'm unsure why that is?

Conclusion:

1. Looking for a way to center DIV's inside a DIV. (Even when page width changes.)
2. To find out why the items do not display as I have created them to in Dreamweaver.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HELP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_scripts/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_scripts/stylesheet_divs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_scripts/stylesheet_header.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_scripts/stylesheet_content.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_scripts/stylesheet_footer.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="background-image-1">
    <div align="justify" class="content-products">
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-cell-bg padding-20">
            <div class="float-left product-cell"><img src="../_assets/fender.png" width="150" height="150"></div>
            <div class="float-left product-cell">Fenders</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to display your group of nested `div`s as inline elements, then declare `text-align: center` on the parent `div` element.

```css
.child {
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d2d2d2;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.parent {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child element</div>
  <div class="child">Child element</div>
  <div class="child">Child element</div>
  <div class="child">Child element</div>
  <div class="child">Child element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you have the answer! By running your snippet it seemed to work EXACTLY how I need! I just need to apply it to my HTML code to see if it works on my end! (Currently its 11:40pm, so no time to do so now haha)

I will mark it as the answer as soon as I get a chance to apply it and it manages to work :)

Comment: Awesome! :) Quite straightforward as well; parent = block, children = inline-block, then it's just a matter of aligning those inline elements, `text-align` works well for that.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was wondering if it was also possible to set the parent to 80% of the page whilst also having THAT centered? Or is it best to create another DIV (named elder haha) outside the parent and make that a block and center parent??

Comment: I worked it in jsFiddle and it seemed to work! :D

https://jsfiddle.net/1sjzw0v7/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: ok I got it @Jesse after looking for your web example. You can add some line in current css rules.

```
.content-products {
    .......
    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

I count total width using each child element is `390px` so we can add margin to separate each of them, with 2 columns will take all `800px`.

```
.product-cell-bg {
    ........
    margin:5px;
}
```

to make it 3 columns, we need to deal with `@media screen` later to detect screen changed, than match it with `.content-products` width.

Comment: That IS what I am looking for, in a way.

I obviously have multiple DIV's inside "r1". What I am wanting to do is space them out evenly across the DIV. Then if the page width is reduced, they drop below each other to fit.

I hope that helped and made a bit more sense! Thanks